# AucTeX Emacs Compilation Problems

Tags: emacs, auctex

I installed emacs23 on my Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit system. I also downloaded the AucTeX tarball and installed it (`./configure` then `make` and finally `make install`). Now I get the LaTeX commands in the menu of emacs and the key-bindings also work well. But I am able to compile only in LaTeX mode. That is, to generate the pdf I have to go the directory and give `pdflatex` command in the terminal. Secondly, I tried the **Other** option in the compilation in emacs but pdflatex is not present as a command there. **I would like to run pdflatex directly instead of LaTeX compilation so that it modifies my pdf**. Secondly, I am not able to run XeLaTeX or LuaTeX in emacs as well. These are the compilation options available for me:

[image] 
Also, I tried a sample code, I am able to compile and get the pdf in the terminal using `latex` and `pdflatex` commands but emacs shows me some error.

[image]

Here is the code which I ran:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\author{Subham Soni S.}
\date{\today}
\title{Installing a new Kernel(ver. 3.13.3) to the Existing Ubuntu Operating System}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
To replace the existing \textsl{kernel} with a new one, do the following:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Download the latest kernel from  \texttt{www.kernel.org}, the files will be compressed in tarball.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The contents of my .emacs file are as follows:

```
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
```

I would like to make emacs a complete IDE for LaTeX. What do I need to do?

Comment: This sentence, "But I am able to compile only in LaTeX mode." suggests that you **are** able to compile, while everything else suggests you can't.  The screenshot does not show you trying to do `C-c C-c <RET>`, which is what normally runs (some form of) LaTeX, BibTeX, Biber, or View.  Also, the clause, "emacs shows me some error", is unclear.  What error?

Comment: The preview stuff is a secondary concern to my mind.  Close Emacs; comment out the line `(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)` in your `.emacs`, re-open the test file and try to run latex (use `C-c C-c` and follow the prompt).  If there is an error, `C-l` will split the buffer and you can browse the details in the newly opened buffer.

Comment: You can add the following to your `.emacs`: `(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)`.  This will globally use PDF-mode.  Alternatively, you can use the 'Local Variables' setting at the end of each file: `%%% Local Variables \n %%% mode: latex \n %%% TeX-PDF-mode: t \n
%%% End:` (where `\n` = newline; it should not be written explicitly).  Similarly, a `%%% TeX-engine: luatex` among the Local Variables will set, for that file, LuaTeX as the engine.  I think something like `(setq TeX-engine 'luatex)` in your `.emacs` would set LuaTeX as the default engine for all files, but I'd have to double-check.

Comment: @jon is right; use PDF-mode.  It's in DVI mode by default; that's why `(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)` is the right line to put into your dotfile.  If you want to try out the setting in the current buffer: `C-c C-t C-p`.  Also, ***please*** use `package.el` to install things :) (Just run `M-x list-packages`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get PDF output by default using Emacs, you can add this to your `.emacs`:

```el
(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

Alternatively, you can declare 'local' variables that are applied per-file.  This is done at the end of the file, using a 'Local Variables' block.  For example ---

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% End:
```

--- tells Emacs that the major mode is LaTeX-mode and that you want to get PDF output rather than DVI output. (You could also add `\pdfoutput=1` in your preamble; but this has nothing to do with Emacs.)  This block, by contrast ---

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% mode: flyspell
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% End:
```

--- tells Emacs you want to use LaTeX-mode, the flyspell minor mode, and use LuaTeX as the backend/engine (LuaTeX produces PDF by default).  Regarding the engine, you can switch, say, to LuaTeX even after the local variables have been set by using.

```el
M-x TeX-engine-set <RET> luatex <RET>
```

Or, if you want to switch to XeTeX, then replace `luatex` with `xetex`.  Note, finally, that we are talking about the engine, so do **not** use `lualatex` or `xelatex` in the above settings.  AUCTEX is usually clever enough to figure out which format (TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt) to use by parsing the file.

Comment: @subhamsoni -- Yes, with Emacs it is best to tell it which engine you want to use and then compile normally using `C-c `C-c` (or the menus).  By default, it assumes you want to use pdfTeX in DVI-mode.  You, reasonably enough, want to change that behaviour.  The question becomes which option should be the global default (pdfTeX in PDF-mode?) and which should be changed locally or per-file. E.g., if for some files, you want LuaTeX, for others pdfTeX, and for yet others XeTeX, then it makes sense to use the Local Variables options.